# Google finance api is working on local server but not working on live

Tags: php

Find me code below just help me

```
<?php 
$result=file_get_contents('http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=DHAMPURSUG');
$res=json_decode(result);
print_r($res);
?>
```

Comment: Does your server have JSON support enabled?

Comment: What error message do you get? What is the value of `$result`?

Comment: there is no error (when run on local server its display all data but when upload on live its display 2-3 data )

Comment: Yes my server is support JSON

Answer (score 2):

Try using basic cURL Post.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=DHAMPURSUG");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
var_dump($server_output);
```

Comment: Getting error after run above code  "Google string(1564) "

411. That’s an error. POST requests require a Content-length header. That’s all we know. "

Answer (score 0):

On your server, `allow_url_fopen` may be set to false, which would prevent `file_get_contents()` from fetching a URL (see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php)).

To figure out whether this is the case, run:

```
var_dump(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'))
```

If `0` or `false` is output on your production server, then you've found your problem. 2 possible fixes:

**Edit the INI file**

One fix is to change your `php.ini` file to set this setting to `1` or `On`.  To find the ini file that governs your script, execute:

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file();
```

Go edit that file, then restart the web server.

**Use cURL instead**

An alternative is to use cURL to connect to google and fetch the info you need:

```
$options = [ 
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://finance.google.com...?client=ig&q=DHAMPURSUG',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if($result===false) die(curl_errno($ch));
```

`$result` now holds the response.

**Addendum**
Another possibility (thanks Hanky Panky) is that the `json_decode` function is not available on your production server. To test this, run the line below to see whether it prints `true`

```
var_dump(function_exists('json_decode'));
```

Comment: What about JSON support in case its an old version?

Comment: @HankyPanky yep, that's  a possibility I didn't think about

Comment: @HankyPanky You're right that's a possibility. It just didn't occur to me. `json_decode` has been part of PHP for 10 years now.

Answer (score -1):

You can upload the htaccess file in the root directory.